# php mail going missing

Tags: php, email

I have an existing php order system that uses php mail() to send out confirmation of orders.
The system has worked well for a few years now but we have a customer who is not receiving any emails. The emails aren't sitting in their spam/junk folder.

Is there a way that I can check to see the routing of the emails?

Comment: Have you checked that the email provider of that customer has not blocked your server?

Comment: Do other customers receive mails?

Comment: yeah - everyone else gets them. I just found out I can do a trace and I get this: virtual_aliases via virtual_aliases router forced address failure

Comment: Is there users email address correct in your database and a valid email format?

Comment: If everyone gets them except for that one client, it's obviously a problem on their end. So there is nothing you can do to check where it's getting stuck because mail is configured properly on your server. They should contact the email provider and ISP, and make sure your server is not blocked for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers - I spoke to the hosting people and we found that because both my site and the customer's site are on the same server there was a confliction. They set permissions for it to work and we should be good to go. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to try to mention the condition that if error occurs [ mail() not sent  successfully ]  exception part has to executed so that you can easily fine the error and correct it .

Comment: I will try to modify the code to find the reason for error .kindly mention with the code which you are using as a specific block alone .